# Merge HTML files into 1 static HTML file

Tags: html

For my project I have 20 html pages with the same footer. Im searching for a way to have the footer in an extern html file and implement/import this file into all the other pages. So that when I need to change something in the footer, I can just do this in 1 file instead of 20.

The thing is that the pages need to be in pure static html, so no scripts included. I cannot insert the footer block with jquery or something like that. It needs to happen "behind the scenes" so that the html output of all the 20 pages is the same as it is now.

I hope you understand my issue and I hope somebody can give me some tips.

Comment: If your server supports server-side-includes you can do this.

Comment: Use some kind of templating engine. E.g. Smarty, Jade (PHP), Handlebars (Javascript)...

Comment: I just use PHP and use php include to include whatever page that needs to be included in the main page (index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't without the use of javascript, or some server side technology. I would recommend read in on server side technologies, like ASP.NET, PHP, or any other.

There is another solution, which depends on your build process: you can create the html content pages, when create a script that inserts the header and footer for you and saves the files to an output folder. Again: it needs some sort of programming to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually yes, there kinda is. But it depends on how much of an aesthetics level you need to achieve.

```
<iframe src="page.html" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

*Would you like to know more?*

https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe